# Dynamically specify argument types based on data

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have an object which defines some transform functions. Those functions have the same number of parameters but different parameter types. I'm trying to figure out a way to make TS to infer parameter types based on a function name.

Let's say we have an object with some functions:

```
const funcList = {
  f1: (val: string, opts: number) => { console.log(val, opts); },
  f2: (val: number, opts: boolean) => { console.log(val, opts); },
} as const;
```

And there is data set that we need to iterate through

```
const data = [{
  func: 'f1',
  val: 'strval',
  opt: 111,
}, {
  func: 'f2',
  val: 222,
  opt: true,
}] as const;
```

And now I want to iterate over that data array and call a corresponding function

```
for (const e of data) {
  funcList[e.func](e.val, e.opt);
}
```

TS doesn't allow this code with the following error

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

It seems that TS doesn't discriminate type based on `func` field.
However if I change the code as the following, everything works

```
for (const e of data) {
  if (e.func === 'f1') {
    funcList[e.func](e.val, e.opt);
  } else {
    funcList[e.func](e.val, e.opt);
  }
}
```

So if I explicitly check element's `func` field, TS can then infer the rest with proper types.

What could I do to avoid using tons of ifs/switch?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nn8qqW) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame thanks for the answer. Your example provides a good sense of the correct direction but doesn't seem to solve the original issue. I tried to iterate over the `data` and it is not working `for (const v of data) { handleFunc(v) }`. And I'd add another optional request. Is it possible to have these functions with a different number of arguments, e.g. `f1: (val: string, opts: number) => {...}`, `f2: (val: number) => {...}`?

Comment: It does work [here](https://tsplay.dev/wj8P6m)

Comment: I'm not sure how can we have different numbers of args, but we can have on object argument in a different shape. Check [this](https://tsplay.dev/wg8R0N). Let me know how you would like to proceed

Comment: Looks really good. Please make it an answer, so I could accept it @wonderflame

Comment: sure, will do in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is unable to handle the "correlated union types" described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), however, there is a suggested refactor described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which considers moving to generics.

First, we will need some map type that will hold the everything related to types of functions:

```
type RecordMap = {
  f1: {
    args: { val: string; opt: number };
    return: number;
  };
  f2: {
    args: { val: number };
    return: void;
  };
};
```

Now, let's create a type for `funcList`, which we will do using mapped types. We will map through `RecordMap` keys and take relevant types from each of its element:

```
type FuncList = {
  [K in keyof RecordMap]: (
    args: RecordMap[K]['args'],
  ) => RecordMap[K]['return'];
};
```

Result:

```
type FuncList = {
    f1: (args: {
        val: string;
        opt: number;
    }) => number;
    f2: (args: {
        val: number;
    }) => void;
}
```

Let's use `FuncList` on the `funcList`:

```
const funcList: FuncList = {
  f1: (args) => {
    return args.opt;
  },
  f2: (args) => {
    console.log(args);
  },
};
```

We don't need to include types in the `funcList` explicitly, since they are inferred from `FuncList`.

Next, we need to create a mapped type for the function arguments, which will return a union of possible arguments, for passed name of the function or for all of them if name is not passed:

```
type FuncListArgs<T extends keyof RecordMap = keyof RecordMap> = {
  [K in T]: {
    func: K;
  } & RecordMap[K]['args'];
}[T];
```

Result:

```
// {
//     func: "f1";
// } & {
//     val: string;
//     opt: number;
// }
type F1Args = FuncListArgs<'f1'>

// ({
//     func: "f1";
// } & {
//     val: string;
//     opt: number;
// }) | ({
//     func: "f2";
// } & {
//     val: number;
// })
type AllArgs = FuncListArgs
```

Since we need a generic argument to make this whole thing to work, we will create a function that will accept an args for some function:

```
const handleFunc = <T extends keyof RecordMap>(args: FuncListArgs<T>) => {
  const func = funcList[args.func];
  return func(args); // no error
};
```

Usage:

```
for (const a of data) {
  handleFunc(a);
}
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wg8R0N)